# Extract KML from Fusion Tables into Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to extract my KML file from Google's Fusion Tables into Google Earth. I follow what I think are the necessary steps via KML Network Link instructions. I must be missing something because no matter what I do the data will not show in Google Earth. I have the Fusion file shared as Unlisted, but am I supposed create a public URL as well in order for the points to show in google earth?

Sorry for the basic/beginner question. It's SO basic I can't find a question already addressing the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two things to check.

1) Your Fusion Table must be "exportable".  Edit->Modify Table Info.  Make sure the exportable checkbox is selected.

2) Did you rely on geo-coding addresses when creating your table?  The lat/long values of geo-coded addresses in Fusion Tables will not be exported in the KML, and addresses might not display in Google Earth.

Eric